# What determines how far an incident stream of electrons will penetrate a material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, diffraction

In the Davisson Germer Experiment, we assume that the incoming beam of electrons undergoes surface diffraction when it hits the nickel. That is, we assume all the electrons hit the top most layer of nickel atoms, and that they then scatter in random directions. We then suppose that upon hitting the top layer of nickel atoms, the electrons behave as waves, which, due to the random scattering, implies that the electrons ought to exhibit a multi-slit interference pattern. The actual experiment shows that such a pattern is exhibited, hence providing evidence that the electrons do behave as waves. My question is how is it that all the electrons hit nickel atoms on the surface and get reflected? Given that atoms are mostly empty space, shouldn't some electrons pass through and then later get reflected?  What determines how far an incident stream of electrons will penetrate a material, and what is the explanation for surface diffraction?